# Projective cover and epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, epimorphisms

Let $C$ be an abelian category and let $X$ be an object with finite length.

Thus there is a composition series

$0=X_0 \stackrel{\iota_0}{\rightarrow}X_1\stackrel{\iota_1}{\rightarrow}\cdots X_{n-1} \stackrel{\iota_{n-1}}{\rightarrow}X_n=X$, where
$X_{i}/X_{i-1}$ is simple.

Suppose that we have projective covers $p_i:P_{i}\to X_{i}/X_{i-1}$ for $i=1, \dots, n$.
Let $P=\oplus_{i=1}^{n} P_i$.

**I want to show that there is an epimorphism from $P$ to $X$.** Here is what I have thought: Consider a short exact sequence $0\to X_{i-1} \stackrel{\iota_i}{\rightarrow} X_i \stackrel{j_i}{\rightarrow} X_{i}/X_{i-1} \to 0$. Since we have a projective cover $p_i:P_{i}\to X_{i}/X_{i-1}$, we have a morphism $f_i:P_i \to X_i$ such that $j_i \circ f_i=p_i$.

Define $F_i=\iota_{n-1}\circ \iota_{n-2}\circ \cdots \circ \iota_{i}\circ f_i$ to be a morphism from $P_i$ to $X$. Then define $F:P\to X$ to be $\oplus_{i=1}^n F_i$.

My guess is that this $F$ is epimorphism but I cannot prove it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you do it by diagram chase, using elements (i.e. in a concrete Abelian category)? You might also want to use induction on $n$. Finally, Mitchell's embedding theorem will generalize it to every Abelian category.